# Inspiron powers down at random

Tags: laptop, power-supply, dell-inspiron

I have a Dell Inspiron 5348 that shuts down at random as if the plug is pulled.

I ran the diagnostics and no fault was found.

I have tried various power outlets in the building but that doesn't seem to matter either.

Any ideas?

Comment: Anything in the System Event Logs?

Comment: Nothing other than the diagnostics I ran this AM

Comment: check your temperatures - seems it's overheating

Comment: The CPU thermistor was 46c in the last diagnostic

Comment: The PSU could be defective and cutting out.

Comment: Check your power settings in the control panel - it could be shutting down due to inactivity. Also, are Windows Updates set to Automatic install? If so, it might reboot as part of this.

Comment: I found out that the PC shuts down when the ethernet cable is plugged in, does this give anyone an idea?